# Azure IoT Hub - DDOS Monitoring

Tags: azure, security, iot, azure-anomaly-detection

For context I’m new to Azure IoT Hub.

I’ve setup a project to monitor air quality on Azure IoT Hub, that captures various telemetry data metrics. I’m now researching how to emulate a DDoS or any malware attack on this application in Azure IoT Hub and monitor this for security anomalies.  How can I emulate this attack and monitor this in Azure IoT hub? Specifically the requirement is -  ‘*If telemetry data is collected from IoT devices and services, such as usage and measurement data, it should be monitored for security anomalies’*.

Thanks in advance.